Sharepoint 2010 workflows cannot be run, updated or saved - Unexpected error
Since yesterday, our SharePoint 2010 workflows have stopped running, and I can no longer save or update them. I receive the following message:

Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were
saved but cannot be run. Unexpected error on server associating the
workflow

I suspect this occurred around the time we installed a Windows patch. All services are up and running with no errors.
Yes, I know the old SharePoint workflows should have been replaced a long time ago, but to my knowledge, they are still supported for another year. We are using SharePoint SE Server (on-premise) and are not allowed to use Power Automate.

I've discovered something. As soon as the workflow tries to read from or write to the list, it won't work. However, if I create a workflow with no interacting with the list, the workflow can be published and run successfully.

Found this - problems with Workflows after applying September 2024 CU for SharePoint 2016/2019/SE: https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2024/09/13/trending-issue-problems-with-workflows-after-applying-september-2024-cu-for-sharepoint-2016-2019-se/

Have you installed recent update for SharePoint?
When you install security update KB5002624 for SharePoint 2016, you must need to install language pack KB5002524 at the same time.
There is a new issue in this update, you might experience an issue in which SharePoint workflows can't be published because the unauthorized type is blocked. This issue also generates event tag "c42q0" in SharePoint Unified Logging System (ULS) logs.
To work around this issue, register the safe types in the Web.config file. You can look for event tag "c42q0" in ULS logs to find the blocked type. If the type and assembly are safe, add the type to the authorized list in the Web.config file.
For example:
<System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>    
   <authorizedTypes>      
     <targetFx version="v4.0">         
       <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WithKey" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
   </targetFx>    
   </authorizedTypes>

Reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2016-september-10-2024-kb5002624-db6c8b15-b9e8-4fa5-a34a-b99a0341271e
